# Coffee Script Array, Object

Tags: meteor, coffeescript, markdown

```
# String of Markdown in DB
beforeMark = @content

# Render string of markdown to html string
afterMark = marked(beforeMark)

# Parse the html to HTML to extract 0, 2, 4th children node (elements)
finalMark = $.parseHTML(afterMark)

# Help needed HERE
# Get 0 2 4th elements if they exist.
# ex) if array has 4 keys, return 0, 2th
#     if array has 7 keys, return 0, 2, 4th
#     if array has 3 keys, return 0, 2th
#     if array has 1 key, return 0th
stringMark = $(finalMark[0]).prop('outerHTML') + $(finalMark[2]).prop('outerHTML') + $(finalMark[2]).prop('outerHTML')
```

I have the above coffeescript I wrote to truncate a markdown string into html of 3 elements.

I need the last part to be more efficient and proper so that it returns the 0, 2, 4th keys of arrays but only if they exist.

I am new to coffee and I need help!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand the problem correctly, I believe you want something like this:

```
stringMark = ''
for data, index in finalMark when index in [0, 2, 4]
  stringMark += data.prop 'outerHTML'
```

Or if you like a little code golf:

```
stringMark = (v.prop 'outerHTML' for v, i in finalMark when i in [0, 2, 4]).join ''
```

Comment: probably need to change `data.prop 'outerHTML'` to `$(data).prop 'outerHTML'`

Comment: @David Weldon works perfectly with PhilVarg's little pointout.